# How do I read OUTPUT parameters in a batch set by a stored procedure before it calls RAISERROR?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In .net when I use `SqlCommand` and call a stored procedure which throws using `RAISERROR`, I can read output variables set by that procedure. However, when calling that procedure from within a T-SQL batch, the `OUTPUT` parameters appear not to be set at all.

How can I read the `OUTPUT` parameter `@OUT_x` from calling T-SQL when the procedure calls `RAISERROR` to indicate an error?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p_x (
     @OUT_x INT OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    SET @OUT_x = 1;
    SELECT 'inner ', @OUT_x;
    RAISERROR('yo', 11, 1);
END
GO

DECLARE @x INT = 0;
SELECT 'initial', @x;
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC dbo.p_x @x OUTPUT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 'catch', @x;
END CATCH
SELECT 'end', @x;
```

Output:

```
------- -----------
initial 0


------ -----------
inner  1


----- -----------
catch 0


---- -----------
end  0
```

I proved that @OUT_x was set to `1` by showing its value within the stored procedure before throwing via `RAISERROR`. I expected the “catch” and “end” entries to be `1`, but it’s as if `OUTPUT` parameter value copying only happens on successful stored procedure completion. [I know I can read these `OUTPUT` parameters when I call stored procedures through `SqlCommand`](https://gist.github.com/binki/6fba7e433389364ce778f03b34b513ae)—why does a T-SQL batch have to be any different?

Is there a workaround that does not involve changing the stored procedure? I really want my stored procedure to throw (`RAISERROR`) in exceptional situations but I also need to use `OUTPUT` parameters to communicate error details.

Comment: A T-SQL batch isn't different. If you put this entire block of code and had it executed through `SqlCommand`, you'd get the same result. Your question is actually about why `TRY .. CATCH` is doing what it's doing (not copying output parameters when the stored procedure does a `RAISERROR`). Erland [covers this](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#systemfunctions) in his peerless article on error handling, but basically, this is just the way it works. You just can't use `TRY .. CATCH` and also get the value of output parameters assigned before the error.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `SqlCommand` returns `1` for the parameter like you would expect.

Comment: @binki, @GSerg: even if you can (and I don't know if you can, I haven't tested it) the key issue here is that `try { ...} catch { ... }` in managed code isn't the same thing as `TRY ... CATCH` in T-SQL. I'm talking about *executing the whole block of code*, including `TRY ... CATCH`, as an `SqlCommand`. Are you really telling me the results are different then? Obviously, if you can, handle errors *outside* T-SQL, because handling them *inside* T-SQL is a hot mess. But I gather from the question that's exactly what's not an option here.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Actually, I was wrong about being wrong. In my test code I forgot to open the connection;-). [Here’s my demo](https://gist.github.com/binki/6fba7e433389364ce778f03b34b513ae) (fix connections strings to run).

Comment: @binki: yes, that's what I thought you meant. The answer is that the TDS parser in `System.Data.SqlClient` doesn't ignore the value assigned to output parameters when the packet for that flies by even if an error happens afterwards, and `TRY .. CATCH` does choose to ignore copying output parameters before entering the `CATCH` (of course, that's an internal mechanism and quite different from networked code). While things are better than before, when we didn't even have `TRY .. CATCH`, it's still not the answer to all woes. The developers give, the developers take away.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Please post that as an answer.

Comment: My goal was to move some logic from C# to T-SQL so that parts of the error handling logic could be run completely by the T-SQL server without requiring my T-SQL client to be low latency and responsive. I ran into this issue because I was using the `OUTPUT` technique for handling errors with C# and wanted to do the same thing but in pure T-SQL. It confused me a while because I assumed it would work the way I wanted and I refused to believe that `OUTPUT` parameters don’t work the same way in T-SQL batches until I isolated that and proved myself wrong :-/

Comment: I think I have a better model of why `TRY…CATCH` prevents reading `OUTPUT` variables whereas `SqlCommand` does read them. If you have `RAISERROR('asdf', 11, 1)`, execution will continue to the next statement (and eventually copy `OUTPUT` parameters to the caller) **unless** you are in a `TRY…CATCH`. Only if you are in a `TRY…CATCH` will T-SQL **immediately** jump to the `CATCH` block—skipping even `OUTPUT` parameter copying. `SqlCommand` does not use `TRY…CATCH`: it lets all the statements run and then generates an `SqlException` if at least one message with severity higher than 11 exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of how `TRY .. CATCH` works: when the `RAISERROR` occurs and the `CATCH` block is entered, it does not copy the values of output parameters back to the appropriate local variables. There is *something* to say for this (the results are likely not to be relied on, since, after all, an error occurred) but it's just as likely an oversight. For starters, no attempt is made to ignore any result sets the stored procedure has produced up to then (and putting results in there is one possible workaround, but it requires changing the stored procedure). As far as I know, this behavior isn't officially documented, as so many things with T-SQL error handling aren't, but Erland Sommarskog's [excellent article](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#systemfunctions) mentions it.

Client code doesn't suffer from the same problem because of the way results are communicated back: when an output parameter is assigned, a TDS packet is sent back to indicate that; when an error occurs, another TDS packet is sent back to indicate that. These things happen chronologically. A client would have to *actively discard* the output parameters on an error, not merely forget to copy them as `TRY .. CATCH` does.

If *all* you are using the output parameters for is communicating error details, consider *not* using `RAISERROR` but making your stored procedure return an error code that the client handles. Of course, you run the risk of external clients forgetting to check this, since they won't actually get an `SqlException`. Another option is to encode all the details you want in the message you pass to `RAISERROR`, or in the `ERROR_STATE()` if it's a small integer. This still requires modifying the stored procedure; there's just no way around that as long as you're intent on using `TRY .. CATCH`.

Comment: This functionality may have been an oversight, as you suggest, but since 2012's THROW works the same way, this looks more like an intentional design decision to me.  Or maybe it was initially an oversight that they decided to leave in ;)

Comment: Thanks. This clearly shows that I am asking for something impossible and provides good suggestions for alternative approaches.

Comment: Though, even if result sets make it through, isn’t it impossible to consume a stored procedure’s result sets from other T-SQL?

Comment: @binki: you've never heard of `INSERT ... EXEC`? (...that probably doesn't work on an error since the whole statement will be rolled back, but I've never tested that.) There's plenty of ways to [share data between stored procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html), though. (Yes, Erland again.)

Comment: There is another option, though I'm loathe to mention it: [`CONTEXT_INFO()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-context-info-transact-sql) will not be reset over an error (obviously) so it can be used to communicate small bits of data across procedures if they're both aware. But this is arguably an abuse of the mechanism, doesn't play nice with others and splitting up binary fields is a pain. If your stored procedure has to change anyway, you may as well include the data in the error message and parse it out (XML would be easy).